# i-adjective modifying ある (eg 強くありたい)

Tags: grammar

So I know that when an i-adjective like 速い becomes an adverb to modify a verb you have to change the い to く, like 速く走る (to run quickly).

I'm having trouble understanding the grammar in 強くありたい. I know it means 'I want to be strong' but shouldn't 強く modify ありたい like the example above? I want to be/to exist/to live *strongly* instead of wanting to posses the characteristic of being a *strong* person.

Comment: 「強くありたいと願い」 is not a sentence.

Comment: Then I'll delete that part, I'm more curious on how the adverb modifies the verb. Maybe it's incomplete. Thanks.

Comment: What is 強くありたい supposed to be. Do you mean 強くなりたい?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. It is from a song, here are the [lyrics](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-72431.html) (second verse). Also, when I do a quick Google Search, the phrase 強くありたい is present in many pages. So I assumed the phrase made sense.

Comment: It's better if you think of 強く as an inflected form of an adjective, not as an adverb.

Answer (score 9):

Japanese i-adjectives (速い, 強い...) are inherently predicates, so in theory they don't need another verb "to be" to support. Here, the extra ある is a kind of rhetorical reflection of the *will* to be (in a state), or consciously keep being.

It can be used in the same way with na-adjectives and nouns in the form ～である. Of course, である can be also just an expanded form of ～だ, so the form is less exclusive than i-adjectives (whose conjugations, like 速かった is contraction of 速くあった too, but it never expands anymore).

> 強くあろうとする *strive to be strong/tough*
>   生涯気高くあった *remained dignified throughout one's life*
>   80歳になっても健康でありたい *want to stay healthy at the age of 80*
>   良き教育者であれ *Be a good educator!*

This is a relatively literary, solemn expression. Also, the difference with ～くなる/～になる is that なる implies you are currently not in the state (80歳になる means you aren't now), which is not the case with ～くある/～である (健康でありたい doesn't mean you aren't now).

**PS**

[adjective]くある also appear when you attach a focusing particle to an i-adjective.

> 薄く**は**あるが、持ち運ぶには重すぎる
>   = 確かに薄いが、… / 薄いことは薄いが、…
>   *It's slim to be sure, but too heavy to carry around.*