# Nuance of 在る for a person in this song

Tags: verbs, song-lyrics

In the song "my code" by GARNiDELiA, there're these two lines:

> 噛｛か｝み締｛し｝めた痛｛いた｝みも　消｛け｝せない傷跡｛きずあと｝も
>
> 私｛わたし｝が私として在｛あ｝るために

I understand what the second line means, and I've read other posts on this site about ある being used for people in some cases, but I'd like to know how the feel of this line would change if いる was used instead.

Also, everything I've read specifically says 在る with that kanji is used for inanimate objects, so why would it be used here to talk about 私?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i-adjective modifying ある (eg 強くありたい)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/64993/i-adjective-modifying-%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-eg-%e5%bc%b7%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84) This type of ある is fairly literary (or even a little poetic), and has a nuance of "stay; go on".

Comment: Hi I notice you have been rolling back my edits that removed [phatic expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression) from your posts. We appreciate your gesture of including niceties in your posts, but FYI [the Stack Exchange convention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/451368) is to leave them out, remove them where they are included, and even have [scripts automatically remove such fluff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/451368). The SE model was designed specifically with no space for fluff and phatic expressions. Upvote answers, like comments that you find helpful.

Comment: @EddieKal Late reply but, I mean I'll keep that in mind, if you wanna make edits then you do you, I won't mind